# How to change column values as new column in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like

```
     Name     Class    Rank
     Karl     Math       1
     George   English    1
     Karl     English    2
     George   Math       3
     Rex      Math       2
     Rex      English    3
```

to change to something like

```
     Name     Math    English
     Karl      1       2
     George    3       1
     Rex       2       3
```

Basically, change the distinct values of class as new columns and remove rank column and insert values directly.

Is there an easy way or in-built python function that could help with this?

I've been searching for ways to do it, but I wasn't able to do it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) the dataframe, like so:

```py
import pandas as pd

before = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Karl', 'George', 'Karl', 'George', 'Rex', 'Rex'],
    'Class': ['Math', 'English', 'English', 'Math', 'Math', 'English'],
    'Rank': [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
})

after = before.pivot(index='Name', columns='Class', values='Rank')
after = after.reset_index()
after.columns.name = None

print(after)
```

Output:

```
     Name  English  Math
0  George        1     3
1    Karl        2     1
2     Rex        3     2
```

You could reorder the columns and/or sort the rows, if you wish.